# React Router v2.7 to v6 onEnter Migration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to migrate an application running on router v3, using the onEnter attribute for route after auth.

onEnter function in YAMain.jsx

```js
    static onEnter(store) {
        return (nextState, replaceState, callback) => {

            // Check if the user is logged in and allowed to make requests before letting them proceed
            store.dispatch({
                type: IS_LOGGED_IN,
                onLoggedIn: () => {
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: GET_SELECTED_LOCATION_AND_CLASSROOM,
                        onSuccess: callback,
                        onFailure: () => {

                            // Get all of the required information from the store
                            const profile = getProfile(store.getState());
                            const selectedClassroom = getSelectedClassroom(store.getState());
                            const selectedLocation = getSelectedLocation(store.getState());

                            // No location has been selected by an admin, go to the locations page
                            if (profile.get('accessLevel') !== 'E' && !selectedLocation.get('id')) {

                                // Return early if this is the page we are going to
                                if (nextState.location.pathname.startsWith('/location')) {
                                    return callback();
                                }

                                replaceState('/location');
                                return callback();
                            }

                            // No classroom has been selected by a user, go to the classrooms page
                            if (!selectedClassroom.get('id')) {

                                // Return early if this is the page we are going to
                                if (nextState.location.pathname.startsWith('/classroom')) {
                                    return callback();
                                }

                                replaceState('/classroom');
                                return callback();
                            }

                            return callback();
                        }
                    });
                },
                onNotLoggedIn: () => {
                    replaceState('/login');
                    callback();
                },
                onFailure: (error) => {
                    if (isTimeGateError(error)) {
                        replaceState('/locked');
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

render function in YARouter.jsx, both classes extend component.

```js
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    {/* Handles the main logic and renders all but one of the pages */}
                    <Route
                        exact path="/"
                        element={<YAMain/>
                        }
                        onEnter={YAMain.onEnter(this.props.store)}
                    >
                        <Route path="/" element={YADashboard}/>

                        {/* Locations page displays the available list of locations */}
                        <Route
                            path="location"
                            element={YALocations}
                        />

                        {/* Classrooms page displays the available list of classrooms */}
                        <Route
                            path="classroom"
                            element={YAClassrooms}
                        />
```

this is not the entirety of the routing but should be enough  to give you an idea of what's going on.

This is what I have now, I have tried a number of things suggested on various places. I'm trying to understand how I can either make this work so I can move on and work on this and make it proper later, OR make it proper now and fix this issue.

How can I go about ensuring proper redirection for user authentication, I've spent 2 days at work trying to figure anything out and am completely stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a way to call `onEnter` when the route is matched and rendered then I think calling it in a mounting `useEffect` hook in a wrapper component is probably what you are after.

Example:

```
const YAMainWrapper = ({ children, onEnter }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onEnter();
  }, []);

  return children;
};
```

...

```
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* Handles the main logic and renders all but one of the pages */}
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <YAMainWrapper onEnter={YAMain.onEnter(this.props.store)}>
              <YAMain />
            </YAMainWrapper>
          )}
        >
          <Route path="/" element={<YADashboard />} />

          {/* Locations page displays the available list of locations */}
          <Route path="location" element={<YALocations />} />

          {/* Classrooms page displays the available list of classrooms */}
          <Route path="classroom" element={<YAClassrooms />} />

          ...

        </Route>
```

Comment: onEnter used to passed in some things, (nextState, replaceState, callback), of which I require functionality from. Is there some easy way to replace this functionality? Perhaps I'm not understanding.

Comment: @MasonFraser What is the purpose of `onEnter`? Have you followed any of the migration guides to update your code? Going from v3 to v6 is a huge jump, especially between v5/v6, lots of breaking changes there. It sort of looks like `onEnter` is Redux middleware, but you aren't using it there. You are dispatching actions, do you just need to refactor those into individual actions that can be dispatched when necessary?

Comment: Yeah it's a huge jump, we inherited this project and have been tasked with updating the application, it was built wrong 6 years ago and now we're paying for it today,

As for that. Yes I suppose that's what I'm looking for. I wanted to reuse the original onEnter that was written to direct the user to whatever page they're supposed to be on as can be inferred from the above onEnter function. I would much rather do it the proper way, but I'm not sure how to go about that either. I've looked at countless migration guides, specifically 3->4 and 5->6, the app is kind of a mix of both right now.

Comment: @MasonFraser I've only experience with RRDv5/v6. Is `onEnter` an old `Route` prop, i.e. something the route handled? Like I said, it looks like a sort of "middleware", but in this case it looks like it has direct access to the routing context to see where routes are transitioning from/to, and can "inject" redirects. RRDv5/v6 don't work like this at all. I think you'll need to break that `onEnter` function down into Redux actions that are passed the RRDv6 `navigate` function in order to interact with the Redux store ***and*** issue imperative navigations.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what onEnter was. It existed up until v4 I believe when it was removed, and I haven't found anything that helps point me in the right direction on how to migrate.

So, if that's what needs to be done, do you have an resources that could show me how to approach this that you could recommend?

Comment: @MasonFraser When I've a moment I'll read up in the older docs, see if something comes to mind.